# How come is it possible that my script works on my computer but when hosted in my raspberry pi it keeps throwing encoding/decoding errors?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, raspberry-pi, ascii

I have a simple script for learning purposes. It scrapes the weather off a website, the currency exchange off another website, and the world news using the Reddit api. Then it packs it all in an email and sends it. When I run this script in my computer (macbook for what it's worth), it just work like a charm, zero problems, no issues. But when I host my script and run it in my Raspberry Pi, all the problems start, mainly enconding/decoding issues.

The full code is too long but basically I have several variables:

this one contains information about the weather which I encode in utf-8 given that the degree symbol gave trouble and it wasn't showing in screen properly:

`weather = weather.encode('utf-8')`

now I have `reddit.posts` list which is a list of the headlines, so far so good, same problem here so I decided to convert it to utf-8 to prevent any issues in the future:

`[x.encode('utf-8') for x in reddit.posts]`

So far so good. When it comes the time to present this information I pack this information in an email, as part of HTML content. I run this script from my computer and it works perfectly, no encoding errors and all characters are shown correctly.

But my surprise comes that this code that runs perfectly in my mac, when I send it over to my Raspberry Pi, starts giving a ton of crazy errors:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb0' in position 353: ordinal not in range(128)`

ALL THE TIME. I have tried to decode the strings again in utf-8 so in one case the code would be something like (simplifying):

```
python
html = """ 
<pre><span style="font-family: 'courier new', courier;"><span style="text-decoration: underline;"><strong>Weather today:</strong></span> {}</span></pre>
<hr />
<pre><span style="font-family: 'courier new', courier;"><strong><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Today's headlines:</span></strong><br /><br />{}</span></pre>
<hr />
""".format(weather.decode('utf-8'), '\r\n'.join(reddit.posts))
```

But it keeps throwing errors all the time.

What really has me baffled is the fact that it works perfectly on my laptop but throws errors in the raspberry.

What's wrong here guys, this is driving me up the wall.

Comment: U+00B0 is degree sign. This indicates the encoding is not UTF-8 as you assume, but Latin-9 or Windows-1252 or compatible. Can't you use a proper HTTP library that automatically decodes correctly according to the Content-Type header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running python **2** on the rasp. Make changes so that you properly run Python 3 there, and the problems should be gone.

The *one* unmistakable hint for it is in your error message:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character **u**'\xb0' in position 353: ordinal not in range(128)

See the "u" there? Python 3 does allow this, for enalbing code compatible with python2/python3 to be written, but it is not displayed in the repr of strings in  error messages.

That said, you'd better have a firm graspping of what are text encodings, and text, with an agnostic representation, as used by Python 3 - it is never late to point one to https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

In other words: you are doing it wrong! :-)  You have to keep text as text, not "encode it to utf-8" - if one of the APIs hapen to deliver you "bytes", then you should "decode" these bytes to *text*, plain strings in Python 3. You do your work, assemble your message, and call the API to send e-mail, which *also* should accept *text*. If you need to encode your text to bytes prior to calling the mail API, then you call `.encode` - just once. For the whole text body.

Comment: I feel stupid, but that was it! I was trying to run the script from the editor that comes from the rasp, when I ran it from the CLI as `python3 myscript.py` it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!!